# Can someone explain the use of foor->bar when calling a function?

Tags: c++

Is it different from foo.bar calling a function from a specific instance? I've seen it around on tutorials but it's never explained and it's too general a term to show up on google.

Comment: What happened when you tried replacing one with the other?

Comment: `foo.bar` is invoking a method on an object, while `foo->bar` is de-referencing a pointer to an object, then invoking that method.

Answer (score 1):

Operator `operator->` can only be used on a pointer type (in that case `foo->bar` is equivalent to `(*ptr).bar`) or a type that overloads `operator->` (in that case the semantic depends on the overload itself).

An example with a pointer type might be:

```
struct some {
    int x;
};

some a{10};
some* a_ptr = &x;

a.x = 10;
a_ptr->x = 10;
```

An example for an overloaded type could be:

```
std::unique_ptr<some> a_ptr = std::make_unique<some>(10);
a_ptr->x = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

`foo->bar` is short for `(*foo).bar`. (Unless `foo` is of some class type for which `->` does something else).

Answer (score 0):

foo->bar is used when foo is pointing to a certain data type
foo.bar is used when foo is an object of a class